# Ability to View Tasks created by users of One profile by users of another profile based on Criteria

Tags: tasks, activities

There are 2 profiles in my salesforce org (health cloud), let's say profile A and profile B. I have a custom field in Activity object, which is named 'Product' (this is a picklist field). We have a screen for Profile A users, which is a task creation screen that includes this 'Product' field as well and this screen is used by Profile A users to create the tasks.

Now the requirement is that, Users from Profile B should be able to see those tasks in the report that are created by Profile A users and have the product value as 'Cryptolis' irrespective of the assignee. The profile B users are by default able to view the tasks that are only assigned to them but not all the records created by Profile A users that have the product criteria.

I've tried 'Task sharing rules' in which I'm sharing the records owned by Profile A users to Profile B users, but I see its not working.

Finally I've tried Role hierarchy, in which I've set it such that Profile A users reports to profile B users though which the profile B users are able to view all the tasks that are owned by profile A users, but it's not filtering based on product criteria and hence I cannot go with this approach.

Please suggest me a solution for this. Note that the OWD settings for Task object : public read/write and for Activities :Private.